# SwipeFlingAdapterView can't swipe when I set onClick listener to a child view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I struggle to find the right answer, so I'll try to explain my problem little more detailed.

So, I have some tinder app with SwipeFlingAdapterView. Inside of that, I have an adapter that holds some textviews and imageview in the middle. I need to enable clicking on that image to open product details, but when i attach onClick listener to it, I can't swipe dragging my finger over that imageview. Only if I start dragging outside of the imageview.

This is the ViewHolder in my TinderAdapter:

```
private static class ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;
    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewSubtitle;
    OnTinderItemClickListener mListener;

    public ViewHolder(OnTinderItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

And this is the method getView from Adapter:

```
ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(mListener);
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_wishlist_tinder, parent, false);

        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image);
        viewHolder.textViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
        viewHolder.textViewSubtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_subtitle);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final FeedItem item = mData.get(position);

    viewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    viewHolder.textViewSubtitle.setText(item.getDetail());
    viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    });
```

So, this onClick listener is making me a problem.. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: try to set the on click in the main activity

Comment: I could set the the listener on whole view pager, but i need to have it only on this image view

Comment: You could also use this library, worked for me:
https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck

Comment: Tnx! but since I don't have that much time to implement and test this, I have to find a way to improvise with this implementation...

Comment: set the onclick in the xml itself and just call the method in the activity

Comment: I don't think that's possible because that imageview is inside of a viewholder in adapter, so that method couldn't be reached in activity, right?  Here's the error I got:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onImageClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView with id 'list_item_image'

Comment: @joe have u sort out the issue as i m facing the same issue ?Could u help me to sort out the issue

Comment: @NitinGupta nope, couldn't find a solution so I improvised with my boss :/

Answer (score 0):

the ImageView consumed the touch event,you have to override it's onTouchEvent

Comment: so i should set on touch instead of on click or?

Comment: but the same problem i get whatever motion event i use.. You have any suggestions?